# Create LINQ query with data submitted through a form

Tags: c#, linq, forms, where-clause

I am a newbie and have searched high and low for an answer to this, but I can't find one.  I have a page (about.aspx) with a form.  On the form is a textbox with an ID of customerID, and a submit button with a PostBackUrl of Default.aspx.  I am trying to create a LINQ query that will search the customerID column of tblCustomerInfo for the value submitted by the form.

I apologize if this is something incredibly obvious that I am just missing.  I have looked at dozens of Web pages, and cannot seem to find an answer to this.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Which linq provider are you using? linq-to-sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave:

Say you have the textbox customerID. You can grab the text from it and use that in the where clause of your LINQ statement:

```
var customerId = customerID.Text;

var customerInfo = (from c in tblCustomerInfo
                   where c.CustomerID == customerId
                   select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope that helps--

Comment: Thansk for the answer, Dave.  I ended up going in another direction, and got it to work that way.